# Como funciona a função "argmin()" e "argmax()" do NumPy?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Alguém poderia me explicar como funciona a função `argmin()` e `argmax()` do NumPy de uma maneira simples e didática?

Comment: O que gostaria de entender?

Comment: para que serve esta função, de uma maneira simples e didática de entender para um iniciante

Comment: pfvr se puder ajudar grato

Comment: Não vejo esta pergunta como ampla, e acho que os 4 votos recebidos poderiam ser repensados.

Answer (score 4):

As funções [argmax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) e [argmin](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) retornam, respectivamente, os índices do maior e do menor valor de um array. Uma ressalva é que, em caso de dois valores iguais serem os maiores (ou menores), elas retornam apenas o índice do primeiro. Dado um array:

```
a = numpy.array([[0, 10, 2],
                 [11, 4, 5]])
```

Usar `numpy.argmax(a)` retorna o índice do maior valor do array `a` como se o array estivesse na forma 1D, ou seja, do `array.flatten()`.

```
>>> numpy.argmax(a)
3
>>> a.flatten()
array([ 0, 10,  2, 11,  4,  5])
>>> numpy.argmax(a.flatten())
3

>>> a.flatten()[3] #retorna o maior valor
11
```

Se o array for 2D (uma matriz), é possível pegar o índice do maior valor de cada lista (ou seja, de cada linha) da matriz usando `axis=1`.

```
>>> index = numpy.argmax(a, axis=1)
>>> index
array([1, 0])
>>> [a[i][index[i]] for i in range(0,a.shape[0])] #retorna os maiores valores de cada linha
[10, 11]
```

Ou, com `axis = 0`, de cada coluna da matriz.

```
>>> index = numpy.argmax(a, axis=0)
>>> index
array([1, 0, 1])
>>> [a[index[i]][i] for i in range(0,a.shape[1])] #maior valor de cada coluna
[11, 10, 5]
```

Uma ultima observação é que, para um array ND, é possível retornar o índice exato na forma do array fazendo:

```
>>> a = numpy.array([[ [1, 2, 3],[4,100,6]], [[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]])
>>> a.shape #Forma de a
(2, 2, 3)
>>> ind = numpy.unravel_index(numpy.argmax(a, axis=None), a.shape)
>>> ind
(0, 1, 1)
>>> a[ind]
100
```

O uso do `argmin` é análogo ao `argmax`.

Comment: Obg Alex!!!! Pela ajuda e paciência...